# ASP Core 1 with PostgreSql. Authorizatioin and authentication

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, postgresql, authorization, asp.net-core

I have a web application based on ASP Core 1 with PostgreSql data storage. And now i want to add auth functionality. I have created base example mvc project with authorization and it works fine with MsSql server. But what about PostgreSql?

At first i create database with same schema (sql was generated via `dnx ef migrations script` and code was updated with pg-style). Then i have configured EF with Postgres

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

When i try to register as new user,  i get an error `42P01: relation \"AspNetUsers\" does not exist`. I have already surrounded table name with doublequotes, but it does not helps. I have no access to default auth models and can't add name atribute to table name and name of fields.

So, my questions are:

1. What wrong with my sample project and why i can't get access to db?
2. More globally. What is the best way to organize authorization and authentication with ASP Core 1 + PostgreSql? I no needed in all ASP auth features, i just neede in roles, i want to have bigint-based id and i want to extend users model (table).

Note: I use EF7.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer for my first question is in the wrong database schema. For someone interested in schema i get the full pg sql code, *but my second question is still opened*.

```
CREATE TABLE public."AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text,
    "Name" character varying(256),
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256),
    CONSTRAINT pk_identityrole PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

CREATE TABLE public."AspNetUsers" (
    "Id" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    "AccessFailedCount" integer NOT NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text,
    "Email" character varying(256),
    "EmailConfirmed" boolean NOT NULL,
    "LockoutEnabled" boolean NOT NULL,
    "LockoutEnd" timestamp without time zone,
    "NormalizedEmail" character varying(256),
    "NormalizedUserName" character varying(256),
    "PasswordHash" text,
    "PhoneNumber" text,
    "PhoneNumberConfirmed" boolean NOT NULL,
    "SecurityStamp" text,
    "TwoFactorEnabled" boolean NOT NULL,
    "UserName" character varying(256),
    CONSTRAINT pk_applicationuser PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

CREATE TABLE public."AspNetRoleClaims" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "ClaimType" text,
    "ClaimValue" text,
    "RoleId" character varying(450),
    CONSTRAINT pk_identityroleclaim PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_identityroleclaim_identityrole_roleid FOREIGN KEY ("RoleId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetRoles" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE public."AspNetUserClaims" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "ClaimType" text,
    "ClaimValue" text,
    "UserId" character varying(450),
    CONSTRAINT pk_identityuserclaim PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_identityuserclaim_applicationuser_userid FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetUsers" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE public."AspNetUserLogins" (
    "LoginProvider" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    "ProviderKey" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    "ProviderDisplayName" text,
    "UserId" character varying(450),
    CONSTRAINT pk_identityuserlogin PRIMARY KEY ("LoginProvider", "ProviderKey"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_identityuserlogin_applicationuser_userid FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetUsers" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE public."AspNetUserRoles" (
    "UserId" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    "RoleId" character varying(450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_identityuserrole PRIMARY KEY ("UserId", "RoleId"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_identityuserrole_applicationuser_userid FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetUsers" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_identityuserrole_identityrole_roleid FOREIGN KEY ("RoleId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetRoles" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, i think the tables should be automatically created as it happens with the SqlServer provider...

Comment: But it doesn't how do I force it to create?

Comment: Do you mean you want EF to create DB automatically? Sometimes it's uncomfortable (at least for me) to use automigration, but you can if you want. There are tons of information how to do it with SqlServer, but for Postgres you have to add specific provider. Note that Postgres is case-sensitive and for property `SomeProp` you will have to write `"SomeProperty"` (with quotes) in sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

I transfer my database from SQL SERVER to postgreSQL, after transfer, I found this error. when I checked my database, the table was in lowercase. I changed all AspTables and columns to default name and solved my problem.